# How to access remote device data while working in visual studio python project?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh

I am working on a python project in visual studio code. I am using a server for it so my current directory is a folder in the server and I want to work on data that is stored on my remote device. I wanted to ask how can I access my data in python, do I need to load the data on the server or can I directly access the data on my remote device without loading it onto the server? I am new to visual studio code therefore I need this help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does this have to do with VSC, the python is running on the server and how do you access the remote device?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can try the remote connection provided by windows or [SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh) in vscode.